# How to specify Assembly attribute in a WiX Fragment generated using Heat.exe from the command line

Tags: wix, wix3, command-line-arguments

I am using Heat.exe to harvest a directory containing my DLLs that need to go into the GAC. The fragment is correctly created and I can build my MSI. The problem I am having is that after the wxs source file is created I have to manually edit the file adding the File/@Assembly =".net" attribute.

Is there a way to have heat include `Assembly=".net"` for each File when using heat.exe from the command line?

Using WiX 3.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no ad hoc attribute for this, probably because you can have your own rules, which files need this attribute, and which do not.

However, you can apply XSLT transform to the heat output and adjust the resulting XML (WXS file) the way you need. Take a look at `-t:<xsl>` switch for more details.